# How can I create these boxes with for each in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a website (related to my homework! which has a javascript code containing three characters, their description, and the number of comments related to them. So far, only one character is visible on the webpage which is "**Finn the Human**"

What I want to achieve is to have 3 boxes display next to each other with the name/description of the rest of the characters.

Here is how it looks like now
[image]

How it's supposed to look like
[image]

It's a type of homework, we need to create those two boxes using the for each cycle in JavaScript. Any ideas on how to do this?

```js
var json = [
    {
        "who": "Finn the Human",
        "wat": "Finn is a silly kid who wants to become a great hero one day. He might not look too tough, but if there's evil around, he'll slay it. That's his deal.",
        "comments": 4
    },
  
    {
        "who": "Jake the Dog",
        "wat": "Finn's best friend is a wise, old dog with a big heart. Jake has the magical ability to stretch and grow. When evil's not running amok, he plays viola with Lady Rainicorn.",
        "comments": 23
    },
  
    {
        "who": "Ice King",
        "wat": "Armed with a magic crown and an icy heart, the Ice King has only one goal: to secure a wife by any means necessary.",
        "comments": 10
    }
]

// What I've tried so far. 

var row = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
var article = document.createElement('article');
var heading = document.createElement('h4');
var link = document.createElement('a');

json.forEach(function(character) {
    article.appendChild(row);
    article.appendChild(heading).appendChild(link);
    console.log(character);
});
```

```css
/* general */
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* clearfix */
.group:before, .container:before,
.group:after, .container:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.group:after, .container:after {
    clear: both;
}

body {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h1.text-muted {
    color: #57aec1; /* questionable */
    /*opacity: .7;*/
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

strong {
    color: #f9c029;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

pre {
    text-align: left;
}


article {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #9F3FA3;
    border-radius: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    /*min-height: 320px;*/

    float: left;
    width: 19.2%;

    padding: 40px 14px;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

article h4 {
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

article p {
    /*margin-bottom: 0;*/
    font-weight: 300;
}

article a,
article a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

article:nth-child(1) { background: #3b9ae1; }
article:nth-child(2) { background: #f6be00; }
article:nth-child(3) { background: #e64134; }



.comments {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 37px;
    width: 40px;
    background: url('chat_b.svg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
}



/* media queries */
@media screen and ( max-width: 820px ) {

    article {
        width: 49.5%; /* 2 elementy su vedla seba, to je 100%, ale medzi nimi je 1% margin, cize 99/2 = 49.5% */
        margin-bottom: 1%;
        min-height: 260px; /* uz mozu byt o nieco nizsie */
    }

    article:nth-child(2),
    article:nth-child(3) {
        margin-right: 0; /* pri druhom a tretom elemente nechceme pravy margin, lebo teraz su na kraji */
    }

    article:nth-child(3) {
        width: 100%; /* treti element je na cely riadok */
    }

}

@media screen and ( max-width: 560px ) {

    article {
        /* uz ziadne marginy */
        margin-right: 0;

        /* elementy budu na celu sirku, pod sebou, ziadne floaty */
        width: 100%;
        float: none;

        /* uz im nebudeme nastavovat minimalnu vysku */
        min-height: 0;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>fun times php</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body class="container">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="text-muted">fun times php</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <article>
            <h4>
                <a href="dude/finn-the-human">Finn the Human</a>
            </h4>
            <p id='idcko'>
                Finn is a silly kid who wants to become a great hero one day. He might not look too tough, but if there's evil around, he'll slay it. That's his deal.
            </p>

            <footer class="comments">4</footer>
        </article>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <p>
            number of dudes: <strong>1</strong><br>
            number of comments: <strong>4</strong>
        </p>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When an element already exists somewhere in the DOM - then `appendChild` does not “clone” it, it will just _move_ it to the new position. You need to create new elements _inside_ your loop, otherwise you are just moving them around in the DOM multiple times.

Comment: That certainly did help so thank you for that guys, however. I am still unsure of how to create more of these boxes with the heading, description, etc.. Everything I've tried so far didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `getElementsByClassName` returns an node list not element, thats what console error was showing. You have two rows, so target first one from list with `[0]`:

   `.getElementsByClassName('row')[0]`
2. you need to create new elements on the fly for each object in loop so move that creation inside loop.
3. you are not accessing your object data at all to insert it into created elements. Use `character.wat` and `character.who`
4. Also research this very useful tool: [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

```js
var json = [{
    "who": "Finn the Human",
    "wat": "Finn is a silly kid who wants to become a great hero one day. He might not look too tough, but if there's evil around, he'll slay it. That's his deal.",
    "comments": 4
  },

  {
    "who": "Jake the Dog",
    "wat": "Finn's best friend is a wise, old dog with a big heart. Jake has the magical ability to stretch and grow. When evil's not running amok, he plays viola with Lady Rainicorn.",
    "comments": 23
  },

  {
    "who": "Ice King",
    "wat": "Armed with a magic crown and an icy heart, the Ice King has only one goal: to secure a wife by any means necessary.",
    "comments": 10
  }
]

// What I've tried so far. 



json.forEach(function(character) {
  var row = document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0];
  var article = document.createElement('article');
  var heading = document.createElement('h4');
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  var footer = document.createElement('footer');
  
  p.innerText = character.wat
  link.innerText = character.who
  footer.innerText = character.comments 

  heading.appendChild(link)
  article.appendChild(heading).appendChild(p).appendChild(footer);
  row.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", article);
});
```

```css
/* general */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* clearfix */

.group:before,
.container:before,
.group:after,
.container:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.group:after,
.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1.text-muted {
  color: #57aec1;
  /* questionable */
  /*opacity: .7;*/
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

strong {
  color: #f9c029;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

pre {
  text-align: left;
}

article {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #9F3FA3;
  border-radius: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  /*min-height: 320px;*/
  float: left;
  width: 19.2%;
  padding: 40px 14px;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

article h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

article p {
  /*margin-bottom: 0;*/
  font-weight: 300;
}

article a,
article a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

article:nth-child(1) {
  background: #3b9ae1;
}

article:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f6be00;
}

article:nth-child(3) {
  background: #e64134;
}

.comments {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 37px;
  width: 40px;
  background: url('chat_b.svg') 0 0 no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
}


/* media queries */

@media screen and ( max-width: 820px) {
  article {
    width: 49.5%;
    /* 2 elementy su vedla seba, to je 100%, ale medzi nimi je 1% margin, cize 99/2 = 49.5% */
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    min-height: 260px;
    /* uz mozu byt o nieco nizsie */
  }
  article:nth-child(2),
  article:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 0;
    /* pri druhom a tretom elemente nechceme pravy margin, lebo teraz su na kraji */
  }
  article:nth-child(3) {
    width: 100%;
    /* treti element je na cely riadok */
  }
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 560px) {
  article {
    /* uz ziadne marginy */
    margin-right: 0;
    /* elementy budu na celu sirku, pod sebou, ziadne floaty */
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    /* uz im nebudeme nastavovat minimalnu vysku */
    min-height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>fun times php</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body class="container">

  <div class="page-header">
    <h1 class="text-muted">fun times php</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <article>
      <h4>
        <a href="dude/finn-the-human">Finn the Human</a>
      </h4>
      <p id='idcko'>
        Finn is a silly kid who wants to become a great hero one day. He might not look too tough, but if there's evil around, he'll slay it. That's his deal.
      </p>

      <footer class="comments">4</footer>
    </article>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <p>
      number of dudes: <strong>1</strong><br> number of comments: <strong>4</strong>
    </p>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```